# CSS- Coloured cox inside form field

Tags: css

I am a newbie but pretty good at CSS, But i can not seem to get my head around doing the following:

[image]

It is the box and background, that is confusing me. The rest i am perfecting fine with. Any pointers would be very helpful. I know bootstrap have a similar plugin, but i find bootstrap a nightmare to use.

I have tired countless of ridiculous things, i am to embarrassed to show, thought is is about time i ask the pro's.

```
  input[type=text]{
  background-color: linear-gradient(90deg, #FFC0CB 50%, #00FFFF 50%);
  color: black;
  }

  input[type=text]{
  background-color: red;
  color: aqua;
  background-size: 20%;
 }
```

HTML

```
 <div id="section_left">
    <form id="franchiseDets" action ="Franchise-Details.php" method="POST">


        <!--                franchise details form-->
        <div class="field">

            <input type="text" name="fran_name" id="fran_name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['fran_name']; ?>"  placeholder="e.g One Delivery Leeds" pattern="[a-zA-Z]" 
                   autofocus required tabindex="1">
            <br>

            <input type="email" name="fran_email" id="fran_email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['fran_email'] ?> ' <?php echo $disabled ?>" placeholder="leeds@one-delivery.co.uk" required tabindex="2">
            <br>

            <input type="text" name="mang_name" id="mang_name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['mang_name']; ?>" placeholder="Joe Blogs" required tabindex="3">
            <br>
```

These are last two ridiculous things i have tired

Comment: Please post some code that you worked on. It is never embarrassing to show your work

Comment: show us what Your try so far, css/html code...

Comment: @IvanStefanov  I've added the code, even though it is pettyful

Comment: @jerneva - check my answer below, I think it would suit what your trying to achieve easily, while is quite flexible if you ever need to change icons without requiring to edit HTML :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method I would usually use. 
Pure CSS and semantics :)

**HTML**

```
<fieldset class="example">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Phone" />
</fieldset>
```

**CSS**

```
fieldset.example {
  position: relative;
}

fieldset.example,
fieldset.example:before,
fieldset.example input {
  height: 33px;
  padding: 0;
  border-width: 0;
  /* remove default border */
}
fieldset.example input {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
fieldset.example:before {
  content: "\0260E";
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 33px;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
```

**LIVE EXAMPLE**

http://codepen.io/KarlDoyle/pen/grRrwG

Comment: I think a `label` might be better than a `fieldset` here though.

Comment: @Paulie_D I prefer not to wrap my inputs with labels. I only ever see people trying that with custom checkboxes. But wrapper element can be anything :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would have solved it with less code as comment suggested:
(Do not evauluate the design)

```css
.input-field {
  /* And border and so on... */
  background-color: #f00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 2em;
  position: relative;
}

.input-field:before {
  content: "X"; /* Use this if the icon comes from a font,
  or relpace it with a space and then use the background-image property */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 2em; /* Just to center the padding */
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em; /* For the scalability */
}

.input-field > input {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1em;
}

/* This is just for play, to test the scaleability */

.fill-row {
  width: 100%;
}

.big {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.short {
  max-width: 160px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-field fill-row">
  <input />
</div>
<div class="input-field big short">
  <input />
</div>
<div class="input-field short">
  <input />
</div>
```

Comment: I would try avoid using span elements for icons. you can get the same effect with less code and being less dependent on any changes made to the HTML

Comment: I would not try to create the smallest code in HTML, even bootstrap uses span as icons, but as you wish :)